# How to detect the size of the parameters that are passed through ellipsis?

Tags: c

The following code works as expected both in [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/bbcdfj) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/WPc79z), however, I believe it contains undefined behavior. The possible reason why it works is that parameters in ellipsis are passed in 64-bit sized blocks in the stack, even if 32-bit sized values are extracted.

```
#include <stdarg.h>                                                                           
#include <stdio.h>                                                                            
#include <stdint.h>                                                                           
#include <inttypes.h>                                                                         
                                                                                              
void foo(int count, ...) {                                                                    
        va_list args;                                                                         
        va_start(args, count);                                                                
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                                                     
                uint32_t x = va_arg(args, uint32_t);                                          
                printf("%"PRIu32" ", x);                                                      
        }                                                                                     
        printf("\n");                                                                         
        va_end(args);                                                                         
}                                                                                             
                                                                                              
void bar(int count, ...) {                                                                    
        va_list args;                                                                         
        va_start(args, count);                                                                
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                                                     
                uint64_t x = va_arg(args, uint64_t);                                          
                printf("%"PRIu64" ", x);                                                      
        }                                                                                     
        printf("\n");                                                                         
        va_end(args);                                                                         
}                                                                                             
                                                                                              
int main() {                                                                                  
        uint32_t a = 1, b = (uint32_t)10000000000, c = (uint32_t)-1;                          
        uint64_t x = 1, y = 10000000000, z = (uint64_t)-1;                                    
        foo(3, a, b, c);                                                                      
        foo(3, x, y, z); // UB                                                                     
        bar(3, a, b, c); // UB                                                                
        bar(3, x, y, z);                                                                                                                     
}
```

Output:

```
1 1410065408 4294967295 // ok                                                            
1 1410065408 4294967295 // ok                                                           
1 1410065408 4294967295 // ok                                                          
1 10000000000 18446744073709551615 // ok
```

If some architecture uses 32-bit offset for implementation of stack in function `foo`, then its result will be incorrect when 64-bit values are passed. In this case output could look like this:

```
1 1410065408 4294967295 // ok
1 0 1410065408 // incorrect
6056184812580896769 12884901887 18446744073709551615 // incorrect
1 10000000000 18446744073709551615 // ok
```

How to correctly implement a single function instead of two functions `foo` and `bar` and be able to call it with both 32-bit and 64-bit arguments?

Comment: I believe th answer is that you cannot. I got bit by this some time ago.

Comment: Please stop using ellipsis! It is an ugly, dangerous construct from old fashioned C.

Comment: @0x5453 It would be great to have answers for both cases if they are different.

Comment: It's impossible with C's variadic parameters (`...`), but can easily be done with C++'s variadic templates.

Comment: Then ask two questions. Removed one of the languages (arbitrarily picked)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: "C++'s variadic templates." Whcih results in a instance of the function for every number of elements. Is this an option?

Comment: Two questions with the same content but different tags? It seems to be even worse than a single question with two tags.

Comment: @Klaus That's a separate question. You always can put the implementation into a non-template function (with a `std::vector` parameter, or something), and force-inline the variadic wrapper

Comment: For c++ start using containers. For c: start using c++ :-)

Comment: @user: At first sight, 2 questions for same problem one tagged C and the other tagged C++ seems bad. When you try to answer, you realize that answers will be quite different in both languages. I did that, and just referenced the older question in the second post, explaining that I also wanted answers for the other language. It does help answerers that are more proficient in one language than in the other one.

Comment: @Klaus funny :-)

Comment: @Klaus: I agree with the first part C++ has tools that help for questions like that. I do not agree for the second part. C is still a very nice language with a large code base. AFAIK, the linux kernel is written in C and not in C++.

Comment: @SergeBallesta:  Even if fully OT: That big projects like linux kernel still using C is not an argument for doing it. If you look inside the linux kernel source you find a lot work arounds to implement inheritance, pseudo OOP and hobbyist container types. And if you look deeper, you see there are not a single approach for each of this. why? Is this really an argument to stay in the past. It is not the "modern is better", but reinvent the wheel only to stay on old style C did help for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes OP's code has UB.

To address the higher level questions:

> How to detect the size of the parameters that are passed through ellipsis?

> How to correctly implement a single function instead of two functions foo and bar and be able to call it with both 32-bit and 64-bit arguments?

Use `_Generic` to automatically distinguish and prefix a type argument.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define GP(X) _Generic((X), \
      uint32_t: 32, \
      uint64_t: 64 \
      ),(X)

void foobar(int count, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, count);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int kind = va_arg(args, int);
    switch (kind) {
      case 32: {
        uint32_t x = va_arg(args, uint32_t);
        printf("%"PRIu32" ", x);
        break;
      }
      case 64: {
        uint64_t x = va_arg(args, uint64_t);
        printf("%"PRIu64" ", x);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  va_end(args);
}

int main(void) {
  uint32_t a = 1, b = (uint32_t) 10000000000, c = (uint32_t) -1;
  uint64_t x = 1, y = 10000000000, z = (uint64_t) -1;
  foobar(3, GP(a), GP(b), GP(c));
  foobar(3, GP(x), GP(y), GP(z));
  foobar(3, GP(a), GP(b), GP(c));
  foobar(3, GP(x), GP(y), GP(z));
}
```

Output

```
1 1410065408 4294967295 
1 10000000000 18446744073709551615 
1 1410065408 4294967295 
1 10000000000 18446744073709551615
```

This is further explored in
[Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485).

Answer (score 0):

> … I believe it contains undefined behavior.

Yes, C 2018 7.16.1.1 2 says:

> … if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> — one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
>
> — one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

> How to correctly implement a single function instead of two functions `foo` and `bar` and be able to call it with both 32-bit and 64-bit arguments?

The C standard does not provide any support for this that is automatic (that is, that conveys type information for you). You must support it manually, by designing some way of providing the information to the function.