# How to detect the size of the parameters that are passed through ellipsis in C++?

Tags: c++

The answer to this question says that C doesn't provide any means to detect the size of parameter passed through ellipsis:
[How to detect the size of the parameters that are passed through ellipsis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154649/how-to-detect-the-size-of-the-parameters-that-are-passed-through-ellipsis)

Is there C++ solution to this problem?

Comment: See the C++ way of doing this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C style vararg functions, no. For C++ style vararg templates, yes. You use `sizeof ...` operator for that. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...Args>
void print_arg_cnt(Args... args)
{
    std::cout << "Arg count: " << sizeof ...(Args) << '\n'; 
}

int main()
{
    print_arg_cnt(1, 1.1, 'a');
}
```

> Arg count: 3

[<kbd>Godbolt</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vq8xz5)

If you want to find out the total number of bytes those arguments occupy, you can do this:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void print_args_size(Args... args)
{
    auto constexpr size = (sizeof(Args) + ... + 0); // +0 for the empty case
    std::cout << "Total size: " << size << '\n';
}
```

Or sizes can be printed individually as in [cigien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63155655/10147399).

Comment: The question is not about the *number* of parameters, but about the *size* of their types in memory. However, I see how it can be achieved using your answer.

Comment: @user it's unclear to what you mean by size of parameters. Do you mean sum of sizes of parameters?

Comment: I mean `sizeof(int64_t)`

Comment: Yes, it perfectly answers the question

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to print the sizes of each parameter type:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void print_arg_sizes(Args... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << sizeof(Args)); 
}

int main()
{
    print_arg_sizes(42, 4.2, 'a');  // prints 481
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4q74K4).

Comment: why do we need parenthesis around `std::cout`?

Comment: @Federico It's just a mandatory part of the syntax for [fold-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).